# How can I append address to <a> tag href

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bxslider

I use bxslider4 and captions is enabled. I want to add link to captions. I done it some but it is applied for just first one. How can I append all links to each captions. I have edited bxslider javascript file.

My slider php code:

```
foreach ($manset_images as $man_img => $value2) {
                                                  ?>

        <div>
            <a  id="slayt_resim_link" href="index.php?url=content&id=<?=$value2->content_id; ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo URL; ?>public/upload/<?=$value2->content_foto?>" title="<?=$value2->content_title?>" data-url="index.php?url=content&id=<?=$value2->content_id; ?>" style="width:100%; height: 350px;">                                
            </a>
        </div>

    <?php 
    }
?>
```

I added below code to original bxslider javascript file to get image link and change caption href:

```
    // find image link
    var captionLink = $this(this)$(slayt_resim_link).attr('href');
    $('#manset_caption_link').attr('href', captionLink);
```

This code provides apply for the first caption. I think I can solve the problem if I add captionLink to href="" 
`<a id="manset_caption_link" href="">`  but I dont know How can I do.

Last state of the javascript code:

```
// bxslider javascript file 719. line   
 /**
     * Appends image captions to the DOM
     */
    var appendCaptions = function() {
      // cycle through each child
      slider.children.each(function(index) {
        // get the image title attribute
        var title = $(this).find('img:first').attr('title');


//------------------ added after ----------------------------
        // find image link
        var captionLink = $this(this)$(slayt_resim_link).attr('href');
        $('#manset_caption_link').attr('href', captionLink);
//------------------------------------------------------------

        // append the caption
        if (title !== undefined && ('' + title).length) {
          $(this).append('<div class="bx-caption"><a id="manset_caption_link" href="---Add captionLink---!!!!!"><span>' + title + '</span></a></div>');
        }

      });
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. Now I can get the all links and append to eah captions.

My php code:

```
foreach ($manset_images as $man_img => $value2) { ?>
    <div>
        <a href="index.php?url=content&id=<?=$value2->content_id; ?>">
            <img src="<?= URL; ?>public/upload/<?=$value2->content_foto?>" title="<?=$value2->content_title?>" data-url="index.php?url=content&id=<?=$value2->content_id; ?>" style="width:100%; height:350px;">                                
        </a>
    </div>
    <?php 
    }
?>
```

bxslider js last state:

```
    /**
     * Appends image captions to the DOM
     */
    var appendCaptions = function() {
      // cycle through each child
      slider.children.each(function(index) {
        // get the image title attribute
        var title = $(this).find('img:first').attr('title');
        var captionLink = $(this).find('a:first').attr('href');
        // append the caption
        if (title !== undefined && ('' + title).length) {
          $(this).append('<div class="bx-caption"><a id="manset_caption_link" href="'+ captionLink +'"><span>' + title + '</span></a></div>');
        }
      });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The major problem here is that you are using the same `id` for each slide in your slider. You can't have more than one unique `id` per page, otherwise you will face non standard behaviour. Your jQuery snippet will correctly append link to the very first `id` it finds (which will always be first slide - even though there are more of them).
*(code below is updated; while I still say that you can't use the same `id` more than once per page, apparently it breaks original bxslider)*

Consider changing your PHP code to use class for `a` element instead:

```
foreach ($manset_images as $man_img => $value2) { ?>
    <div>
        <a id="slayt_resim_link" class="slayt-resim-link" href="index.php?url=content&id=<?=$value2->content_id; ?>">
            <img src="<?= URL; ?>public/upload/<?=$value2->content_foto?>" title="<?=$value2->content_title?>" data-url="index.php?url=content&id=<?=$value2->content_id; ?>" style="width:100%; height:350px;">                                
        </a>
    </div>
    <?php 
    }
?>
```

Then your jQuery snippet could look like this:

```
    //------------------ added after ----------------------------
    // find image link
    var captionLink = $(this).find('#slayt_resim_link').attr('href');
    //------------------------------------------------------------

    // append the caption
    if (title !== undefined && ('' + title).length) {
        $(this).append('<div class="bx-caption"><a id="manset_caption_link" href="' + captionLink + '"><span>' + title + '</span></a></div>');
    }
```

I strongly discourage you from editing original slider files though. Make your own JS file and add to your project instead, after jQuery and BXSlider were loaded:

```
(function() {
    var slides = jQuery('.slayt-resim-link');
    slides.each( function() {
        var captionLink = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).find('.bx-caption a').attr('href', captionLink);
    });
})();
```

Comment: it does not work. When I changed id to class bxslider broke.

Comment: Okay, let's use both id and class then. I have updated my code

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful effort. I have removed 2 lines added before on bxslider.js . I have added `var captionLink = $(this).find('a:first').attr('href'); `